# jQuery: OnClick the title video is correct, but url is of next video

Tags: jquery

I have a search page like

```
<div class="">
    <input id="search-input" type="text" class="input-medium search-query span4">
</div>

<div id="result">

</div>

<div id="result-template">
    <div class="hide-item item" id="item">
        <div style="float:left">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div id="name">
            <p class="title"></p>
            <p class="views"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and jQuery as

```
$(function(){
    $('#search-input').live('keyup',function() {
        var search_input = $(this).val();
        var keyword = encodeURIComponent(search_input);
        var yt_url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q='+keyword+'&format=5&max-results=10&v=2&alt=jsonc';

        $.ajax({
          url: yt_url,
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
            //called when complete
          },
          success: function(response, textStatus, xhr) {
            if(response.data.items) {
                var template = $('#item').clone();
                $('#result').html(template);
                $.each(response.data.items, function(i, data) {
                    console.log(data)
                    search_data = {
                        'id': data.id,
                        'title': data.title,
                        'views': data.viewCount,
                        'thumbnail': data.thumbnail['sqDefault'],
                    }
                    video_result_template(search_data);
                });
            } else {
                // var template = $('#item').clone();
                // $('#result').html(template);
            }
          },
          error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //called when there is an error
          }
        });
    });
});

// filling out the search template
function video_result_template(data) {
    var item = $('#item').clone();
    item.removeClass('hide-item');
    item.find('img').attr('src', data.thumbnail);
    item.find('.title').html(data.title);
    item.find('.views').html(data.views);
    $('#item').attr('id', data.id);
    item.addClass('view-item');
    // $('#result').append(item).fadeIn(); // slow/fast?
    $('#result').append(item).fadeIn('slow');
}
```

I get the results on the div with title, views, url. Now when I click div, the following jQuery is fired

```
$(function(){
    $('.item').live('click', function(){
        // alert(this.id);
        console.log($(this));
        var url = $('#video-frame').attr('src');
        var new_url = url.replace(/embed\/[\w -]*/g, 'embed/' + this.id);
        alert($('.title').html() + ',' + new_url);
        $('#video-frame').attr('src', new_url);
    });
});
```

which alerts right title but the url(or video_id is of the next video in the list).

When I see my html from firefox I see the following

```
 <div id="result" style="display: block;">
    <div id="lqT_dPApj9U" class="item view-item">
      <div style="float: left;"><img alt="" src=
      "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/S2nBBMbjS8w/default.jpg" class="thumbnail" /></div>

      <div id="name">
        <p class="title">Coke 2012 Commercial: "Catch" starring NE_Bear</p>

        <p class="views">619167</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="hKoB0MHVBvM" class="item view-item">
      <div style="float: left;"><img alt="" src=
      "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/lqT_dPApj9U/default.jpg" class="thumbnail" /></div>

      <div id="name">
        <p class="title">Coca-Cola Happiness Machine</p>

        <p class="views">4791156</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="item" class="item view-item">
      <div style="float: left;"><img alt="" src=
      "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/S2nBBMbjS8w/default.jpg" class="thumbnail" /></div>

      <div id="name">
        <p class="title">Coke 2012 Commercial: "Catch" starring NE_Bear</p>

        <p class="views">619167</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

- If seen clearly the first and last div has same data elements
- infact the difference is that the last div is copy of first element
- The last element has invalid id="item"(must be video id)

**Question**
How can I fix this issue?

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/hhimanshu/F5NHK/

**Required**
After search, click on any video div and it must give right video id and title
P.S. in fiddle clicking on list is not doing anything(don't know why, it works on my system though)

Comment: firstly, your code is all kinds of broken. `id`'s can only be used once, if you want to have multiple, use classes. Surely you can just change `$('#item').attr('id', data.id);` to `item.attr('id', data.id);` to get the correct `id`.

Comment: `var url = $('#video-frame').attr('src');` url is undefined, not getting src from `video-frame`.

Comment: I commented that out <!--iframe id="video-frame" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/gSy4HeDjPvs?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe-->, please uncomment, and you will get url

Comment: @ahren, this works, what is the difference between the two ?

Comment: the difference is, one is the item in the dom (`$("#item")`), and one is the item variable that you're inserting later (`item`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function

```
// filling out the search template
function video_result_template(data) {
    var item = $('#item').clone();
    item.removeClass('hide-item');
    item.find('img').attr('src', data.thumbnail);
    item.find('.title').html(data.title);
    item.find('.views').html(data.views);
    $('#item').attr('id', data.id);
    item.addClass('view-item');
    // $('#result').append(item).fadeIn(); // slow/fast?
    $('#result').append(item).fadeIn('slow');
}
```

replace `$('#item').attr('id', data.id);` to `item.attr('id', data.id);`

Thank you @arhen for providing this solution

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your item-remplate from the #results div. Maybe you will have to fix the click bindings.
I tested in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F5NHK/2/) and seems to work. **Tell if it doesn't**, i tried to fix it doing minor changes in your code.

Suggestion, check [jquery templates](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/)

Comment: Thanks Chris, I removed the template and put that in result div. I will take a look at the jquery templates, Thanks for the reference, appreciate your help